# tkinter: bind Return key to the OK button -- but not to the Text widget

Tags: python, binding, tkinter

With `tkinter/ttk (8.5+)`, in a custom dialog, I want to bind the `Return` key to the `OK` button.
So I use the standard instruction:

```
self.window.bind("<Return>", self.on_ok)
```

The problem is, in this custom dialog there is also a (multiline) `Text` widget. And once the `Return` key is bound to the `OK` button, it's no longer possible to type `Enter` in the `Text` widget without terminating the dialog! Typing `Return` is now equivalent to pressing `OK`.

I checked in Firefox and, when a `Text` control has the focus, pressing `Return` doesn't fire the OK button. It justs enters a newline character.
If the `OK` button has the focus, then pressing `Return` activates the button.

Is there a way of reproducing this behavior in tkinter? Meaning, a binding that fires the `OK` button only if the `Text` widget is not selected?

Comment: clarification: _"And once the Return key is bound to the OK button,"_ -- you aren't binding to the button, you are binding to every widget in the dialog.

Comment: @BryanOakley: exactly. That was the problem for which the question was asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options.

1. Choose a different binding for the `self.on_ok` function, like `'<Shift-Return>'`.
2. Have the function check for which widget has focus. If `self.window` is your root `tkinter` object:

```
def on_ok(event):
    if self.window.focus_get() == text:
        print('the text widget has focus')
    else:
        print('some other widget has focus')
```

Comment: Yes that works fine. Problem solved. I thought I would have to do something to manually implement a carriage return when the text had the focus but that's not the case. The carriage return takes place automagically, so your solution works perfectly.